# ./configure doesn't find Qt5Core, QT5GUI, QT5Widgets

Tags: installation, compilation, qt5

I've recently replaced Win10 by Linux Debian 11.2 on my PC (hence I'm a newbee in Linux). Now, not all programs are available as deb-Files.
I tried to compile source code - here a synthesizer ams-2.2.0 - from a tar.gz files (after unzipping into a separate folder) with steps (as written in the INSTALL.TXT to this source, and obviously usual)

```
./configure
make
make install
```

I get a bunch of error messages for missing files, when running `./congigure` most resolved by installation of missing packages, but at last it fails with error message:

```
checking for QTCore Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets >= 5.0... no
configure: error: cannot find Qt5 library >= 5.0
```

(hope to get all written correctly, because I can't copy from the terminal ... Ctrl-Shift-C doesn't seem to work)

I checked the installation in synaptics and found that Qt-Version is 5.12. So what's wrong here?

I'm afraid to have this error message everytime I try to compile different source codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install libqtcore and libqtwidgets with development headers, they are in `qtbase5-dev` package.

```
sudo apt install build-essential qtbase5-dev qtchooser
```